# Receive randomized rows as new csv

Tags: python, csv, random

I am quite new to python (and mainly want to use this for academic reasons), so please bare with my question!

I have collected twitter data through their dev academic account - however the amount is quite big, so I want to create a randomized sample.
I already have the data as json as well as csv format.

I now want to get a randomized sample of x rows (let's say 1000 rows) (preferably for a specific column (column "CG" (header=text)) - if that's difficult values for the whole row should be regardded)

What I found is this code, that gives out randomized values.

1. How can I amend it in a way it will give out randomized rows, but not random values - so they will always contain the content from the same column?
2. How can I have this create a new csv with the randomized row data as sample?

P.s.: I also tried to get datatools running and make use of their csvrows tool, however although following the instructions I couldn't get the csvrow tool to run. [datatools](https://caltechlibrary.github.io/datatools/how-to/select-random-rows-from-a-CSV-file.html)

MWE:

```
import csv
import random

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:

    lines = [tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(csv_file)]


n = 1000 #  number of row you want to pick elements from

chosen_rows = random.choices(lines, k=n) 
 # pick n rows in the list

chosen_values = [random.choice(row) for row in chosen_rows]
  # pick a value from each row

print('\n'.join(chosen_values))
```

Comment: Do you need to achieve this using python only or shell commands also fine?

Comment: Hey @BarathVutukuri it doesn't "need" to be python ,if you have another idea - shoot :) !

Comment: I'm assuming you're in Linux environment. You can use `shuf` command in linux to shuffle the csv records in your file, so you get random records all the time. `(head -1 input.csv ; tail +1 input.csv | shuf ) | head -1000` This will shuffle all the records and gives you 1st 1000 records along with header..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)? It is widely used to handle csv/json files and data in academia, data science and industry.

Here's an example which does what you want in 2 lines of code, without all the hassle of writing extra code.

```
import pandas as pd
# read csv
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_your_file)
df.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=12345)
```

[Pandas documentation for sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

Comment: Thank you! Sounds good! If I got the documentation correctly, If I use frac it will not create a fixed number of rows, but rather a percentage of total rows, right?How would I be able to get the results printed as csv? I created a file and added the path, yet this will not output anything as of now :s

Comment: Yeah, you can use any fraction to sample. I used 0.5 as an example. btw, if you use 1 in `frac`, it will  shuffle your dataframe. `df.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=12345)` will automatically print your sampled dataframe. If you want to make a new dataframe, just use `new_df = df.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=12345)`. You can then export it as `new_df.to_csv(file_path')`.